# Want to Wrap PSList in a Powershell function to use pipeline values

Tags: powershell, pipelined-function

I like PSList, and use the CPU and Elapsed times to indentify processes that need to be killed.  I would like to wrap it in a powershell function that returns pipeline values so that I could do something like the following:

```
get-remoteprocess server1 | where  {$_.CPUMinutes -gt 4}
```

I get stuck in *returning values from the function* - which I understand would need to be an array of objects.

Heres what my first version looks like:

```
function get-remoteproc {
param ($hostname)
$results = pslist "\\$hostname" 

for ($i= 3; $i -le $results.length; $i++) {
    $strline = $results[$i]
    $StrWithPrefix = " "+$results[$i]
    $trimmedline = $StrWithPrefix -replace '\s+', " ";
    $Splitline = $trimmedline.Split(" ")
    $ProcessName = $Splitline[1]
    .
    .
    $ProcessCPUTime = ":"+[string]$Splitline[7]
    $SplitCpuTime = $ProcessCPUTime.Split(":")

    $CpuHours = $SplitCpuTime[1]
    $CpuMinutes = $SplitCpuTime[2]
    $CpuSeconds = $SplitCpuTime[3]
    .
    .
    .

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
       $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name "Name" -Value $Name
       $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name "PPid" -Value $Ppid
       $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name "Pri" -Value $Pri

}
```

Taking Doug Finke's suggestion, which is pleasingly terse, here is my slightly adapted version, which works well with pipeline values.

```
function get-remoteproc {
    param ($hostname=$env:COMPUTERNAME)

    $results = PsList "\\$hostname"

    foreach($record in $results[3..($results.Count)]) {
        # Remove spaces
        while ($record.IndexOf("  ") -ge 0) {
            $record = $record -replace "  "," "
        }

        $Name,$Processid,$Pri,$Thd,$Hnd,$Priv,$CPUTime,$ElapsedTime = $record.Split(" ")

        $properties = @{
            Name = $Name
            Pid = $Processid
            Pri = $Pri
            Thd = $Thd
            Hnd = $Hnd
            Priv = $Priv
            CPUTime = $CPUTime
            ElapsedTime = $ElapsedTime
        }

        New-Object PSObject -Property $properties |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUH   {[int]$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[0]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUM {[int]$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[1]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUS {[int]$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[2]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty ElaH {[int]$this.ElapsedTime.Split(":")[0]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty ElaM {[int]$this.ElapsedTime.Split(":")[1]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty ElaS {[int]$this.ElapsedTime.Split(":")[2]} 
    }
}
```

And a call to the function, which shows that the objects are unrolled correctly for consumption by the pipeline:

```
get-remoteproc "Server1" | where {(($_.CPUM * $_.CPUS) -gt 60) -and ($_.name -notmatch "Idle" )}|
ft name, pid, pri, thd, hnd, priv, CPUH, cpuM, cpuS, ElaH, ElaM, ElaS   -auto
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: your function is missing a closing curly bracket, without which is difficult to say what's not going fine in your code

Answer (score 1):

As empo points out, you need to emit the $obj back to the pipeline. Here is another way to work the plist text into PowerShell objects.

```
function get-remoteproc {
    param ($hostname=$env:COMPUTERNAME)

    $results = PsList "\\$hostname"

    foreach($record in $results[3..($results.Count)]) {
        # Remove spaces
        while ($record.IndexOf("  ") -ge 0) {
            $record = $record -replace "  "," "
        }

        $Name,$Processid,$Pri,$Thd,$Hnd,$Priv,$CPUTime,$ElapsedTime = $record.Split(" ")

        $properties = @{
            Name = $Name
            Pid = $Processid
            Pri = $Pri
            Thd = $Thd
            Hnd = $Hnd
            Priv = $Priv
            CPUTime = $CPUTime
            ElapsedTime = $ElapsedTime
        }

        New-Object PSObject -Property $properties |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUHours   {$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[0]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUMinutes {$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[1]} |
            Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty CPUSeconds {$this.CPUTime.Split(":")[2]} 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return an array of values passed to the pipeline one by one, you just need to return multiple values in your function. For example:

```
function get-remoteproc {
param ($hostname)
  $results = pslist "\\$hostname" 
  for ($i= 3; $i -le $results.length; $i++) {

    # your staff to $obj

    # output $obj
    $obj
  }
}
```

The function result is an array of `$obj`. When connected to a pipeline the array will be enrolled, and all the values will be passed to the stream one by one.

Comment: In order to output an object the line `$obj` is quite enough. Use of `$objs` is not effective in here (and `+=` for such arrays is a very slow operation, FYI).

Comment: $objs would not be effective, but I believe ,$objs would be.

Comment: @Roman: I don't think so. Functions work differently from filters. In here the function must return an array so that it can be processed in the subsequent pipelines.

Comment: If you return $objs, it will get unrolled on the return into a stream of objects, instead of a single array object.  If you return ,$objs it will return the entire array as a single object.

Comment: @empo, your array in the last line `$objs` is actually unrolled and the result is the same as if the function outputs `$obs` from inside the loop instead of at first collecting items (slow) and then returning them as `$objs`. Try it.

Comment: @empo: "Functions work differently from filters" - this is probably not true about how they return/output data. What do you mean?

Comment: ok guys! You are true. I think my example is totally wrong as long as return values must be piped one by one to the next stream. I'm going to improve the answer then. Thanks