# How to pipe 'Elapsed Time' (or other output) from PsList

Tags: powershell, admin, pipeline, sysinternals

This task is incredibly simple yet I can't seem to figure it out (all the more reason it's frustrating) - I would like to query PsList for a particular process and return a specific portion of it's regular output. In example, I would like to return **only** the 'Elapsed Time' field from the PsList output below

```
Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time 
RDCMan             7384   8  22 1316  60432     0:00:54.101     5:02:31.886
```

such that psuedocode and behavior would be as follows:

```
pslist rdcman | select Elapsed Time
 > 5:02:31.886
```

Note: 'select' doesn't actually work in this way.

The following [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927129/want-to-wrap-pslist-in-a-powershell-function-to-use-pipeline-values) dances around the desired output and may be of value although I can't seem to massage it to my needs.

I've tried to find pslist's source code (no luck) to see if reverse engineering could enlighten, and played with `pslist rdcman | Get-Member`. None of the member information was readily informative.

Any advice?

Comment: It looks like PsList is just returning raw string output, which means you will need to parse it like the linked code snippet has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for whatever reason you have your heart set on the output from pslist you could also do this to make it into a PowerShell object

```
$output = .\pslist.exe 2> $null 
$output | Select -Skip 3 | ForEach-Object{
    $procInfo = $_ -split "\s+"
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Name = $procInfo[0..($procInfo.Count -8)] -Join " "                
        Pid = $procInfo[-7] 
        Pri = $procInfo[-6] 
        Thd = $procInfo[-5] 
        Hnd = $procInfo[-4] 
        Priv = $procInfo[-3]     
        "CPU Time" = $procInfo[-2]  
        "Elapsed Time" = $procInfo[-1] 
    }
} | Format-Table
```

`.\pslist.exe 2> $null` was to [suppress the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380227/psexec-throws-error-messages-but-works-without-any-problems) output generated from pslist. We skip the first couple of lines in the output since the should be the same everytime.

```
Process information for WYVERN:

Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time
```

Then we split each line on groups of space to get an array. The next part should not have been as complicated but since EXE names can contain spaces we needed to account for that. The last 7 columns should never contain space so those were explicitly assigned in the `[pscustomobject]` that was created. Of the few items from that that we not assigned we created a space delimited string. `Format-Table` is there merely to make it pretty on screen. If you need to manipulate the output do so in front of the `| Format-Table`.

**Sample Output**

```
Name                      Pid   Pri Thd Hnd  Priv    CPU Time       Elapsed Time 
----                      ---   --- --- ---  ----    --------       ------------ 
Idle                      0     0   4   0    0       1059:54:59.735 0:00:00.000  
System                    4     8   146 952  220     2:13:41.415    300:01:13.336
smss                      312   11  3   32   580     0:00:00.062    300:01:13.320
csrss                     512   13  10  858  3076    0:00:20.139    300:01:09.763
wininit                   628   13  3   82   1688    0:00:00.062    300:01:07.985
csrss                     644   13  12  1514 5540    0:19:56.168    300:01:07.969
services                  696   9   7   274  7056    0:00:39.296    300:01:07.798
```

In the case of getting information for *rdcman* you could just try the following. This code is in place of the last line of the code above

```
} | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "rdcman"} | Select -ExpandProperty "Elapsed Time"
```

or

```
} ?{$_.Name -eq "rdcman"} | Select -Expand "Elapsed Time"
```

Comment: After changing `$output = .\pslist.exe 2> $null` to `$output = pslist.exe 2> $null` I was able to run this code. Taking the 'make your own object' route by copying the output seems more circuitous than directly filtering pslist's result but remains useful. Thanks @Matt!

Answer (score 2):

Get-Process has a startTime property, so the current time minus this can give the elapsed time that pslist provides.

```
(get-date) - (get-process rdcman).StartTime
```

This return a powershell timespan object, so you can format it to d.hh:mm:ss with

```
"{0:c}" -f  ((get-date) - (get-process rdcman).StartTime)
```